# How to generate opencv documentation in pdf from OpenCV doc dir

Tags: opencv

In OpenCV source dir, there is a doc dir. But, this dir contains no pdf files. How can I get files like "opencv_tutorials.pdf", "opencv_cheatsheet.pdf"?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need doxygen for this. You can install it from http://www.doxygen.nl and then run the doxygen executable on the doxyfile.in. This should generate documentation files in html, pdf (if you have latex installed), etc.

Note that you'll probably find all the tutorials and PDFs you'll need online as well. Using these generated files have the risk of being outdated very soon.

Comment: @Ayoung if you found the answer useful or if it answered your question, please mark it as useful and accepted.